# How do I filter for the same information in Notepad++?

Tags: replace, notepad++

I have a text file in Notepad++ with the following structure:

```
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "https://randomurl",
   "id": "39004",
   "title": "RandomTitle",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "https://www.randomurl",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "randomurl"
```

Wherever it says `randomurl` there is a different URL address.

This structure is repeated in my document a couple thousand times. (however the information of "title, url" etc. is different for each.)

What I'd like to do is filter out (from each structure) only the following information:

```
"title": "RandomTitle"
"url": "https://www.randomurl"
```

The rest can be deleted.
How would I go about doing that with Regex? (I assume)

Comment: What have you tried?
Where are your attempts?
What doesn't work?

Comment: I haven't used Regex in a while so at the moment I haven't tried anything. I just know that Regex can potentially solve this.

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*"(?:title|url)".*\R(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[\s\S]`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
    .*              # 0 or more any character but newline
    (?:             # non capture group
        title           # literally
      |               # OR
        url             # literally
    )               # end group
    "               # quote
    .*              # 0 or more any character but newline
    \R              # any kind of linebreak
    (*SKIP)         # skip this match
    (*FAIL)         # and consider match has failed
  |               # OR
    [\s\S]          # any character
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to achieve this. @Toto gives a way using regular expression. Another way uses Bookmarking.

Using the "Mark" tab of the search panel (or menu => **Search** => **Mark**). Enter `^"(title|url)":` into the search parameters, ensure "Bookmark lines" is selected, and click on **Mark All**. Expect to see blue blobs at the left of the marked lines. Now use menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Remove unmarked lines**. Alternatively, could use menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Copy bookmarked lines** and paste them elsewhere (even into another application).

The **Mark All** step could be split into two steps. This style might be useful if more complex searching is needed. Proceed as above but enter `^"title":` into the "Find what" field, then click on **Mark All**. Note that the "title" lines have blue blobs. Next enter `^"url":` into the "Find what" field, ensure that "Purge for each search" is not selected, then click on **Mark All**. Note that now both "title" and "url" lines have blue blobs. As above, can now do a **Remove unmarked lines** or **Copy bookmarked lines**.